# Programmatically script SSIS package - Dynamic XML to OLE DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis, etl

I've been trying to piece together how other users have finished their projects, but my understanding is still limited.

I want to take any given XML source, make a Data Flow Task, and pass its data to an OLE DB destination matching the table name of the XML file. Running it with the visual tool means I cannot do dynamic data flow tasks because the Metadata does not refresh.

I have created a script that creates a package, but when I open the package in Visual Studio, it has a red-x saying that there cannot be zero Input Columns. When I drill down and look at the mappings of the OLE DB Destination, then click OK - it corrects it for me. I cannot figure out how to do that programmatically.

I've seen others solve it by using foreach loops and going through the Input columns, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I also have a separate script that I tried to mimic several people's scripts with, and it has different issues. Not sure how to post it as an attachment

Thank you in advance for the help :)

***EDIT***

I've been getting positive feedback for trying out BIML, and I will...but I want to know if in the short term anyone can help me figure out why this doesn't fill in ExternalMetaDataColumnId for my input. I've posted my updated code below with foreach loops that aren't doing what I expect them to.

Thank you
        #region
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
    using System.Xml;
    #endregion

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Initial Setup
            Application a = new Application();
            Package p = new Package();
            TaskHost t = p.Executables.Add("DTS.Pipeline") as TaskHost;
            t.Name = "DataFlow Task";
            t.Description = "Flat File to Database";
            MainPipe mp = t.InnerObject as MainPipe;
            #endregion

            #region Flat File Source in Dataflow Task
            IDTSComponentMetaData100 md = mp.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New(); 
            md.ComponentClassID = "Microsoft.XmlSourceAdapter"; 
            md.Name = "XML Source"; 
            CManagedComponentWrapper wrp = md.Instantiate(); 
            wrp.ProvideComponentProperties(); 

            #endregion

            #region Add connection manager to OLE DB
            ConnectionManager conn = p.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
            conn.Name = "westcoastuserDBO";
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DBO;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;";
            #endregion


            #region XML Source Properties
            wrp.SetComponentProperty("XMLData", @"C:\Users\file.xml");
            wrp.SetComponentProperty("XMLSchemaDefinition", @"C:\Users\file.xsd");
            wrp.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 0);
            wrp.SetComponentProperty("UseInlineSchema", false);
            //below does not work
            //wrp.SetComponentProperty("XMLIntegerMapping", 0).TypeConverter = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.XmlSourceAdapter + XMLIntegerMappingConverter";

            wrp.ReinitializeMetaData();
            wrp.ReleaseConnections();
            IDTSComponentMetaData100 md2 = mp.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
            md2.ComponentClassID = "Microsoft.OLEDBDestination";
            CManagedComponentWrapper wrp2 = md2.Instantiate();
            wrp2.ProvideComponentProperties();
            md2.Name = "OLE DB Connection";
            md2.UsesDispositions = true;
            md2.Version = 4;
            wrp2.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", "dbo.authorizations");
            #endregion

            IDTSPath100 path = mp.PathCollection.New();
            path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(md.OutputCollection[0], md2.InputCollection[0]);

            IDTSInput100 input = md2.InputCollection[0];
            IDTSVirtualInput100 vInput = input.GetVirtualInput();

            //below taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587709/c-sharp-ssis-data-flow-component-creating-custom-input-columns
            IDTSExternalMetadataColumnCollection100 externalColumnCollection = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection;


            // Iterate through the virtual input column collection.
            foreach (IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 vColumn in vInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection)
            {
                // Call the SetUsageType method of the destination
                // to add each available virtual input column as an input column.
                wrp2.SetUsageType(
                   input.ID, vInput, vColumn.LineageID, DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY);
            }

            // Get the destination's default output collection
            IDTSOutputCollection100 outColl = md2.OutputCollection;

            // Iterate through the outputs in default output collection
            foreach (IDTSOutput100 output in outColl)
            {
                // Iterate through the default output columns in the output 
                int count = output.OutputColumnCollection.Count;
                foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 outputColumn in output.OutputColumnCollection)
                {
                    // Get the output's external metadata column collection
                    IDTSExternalMetadataColumnCollection100 extMetadataColumnColl = output.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection;

                    // Iterate through the external metadata column collection's external metadata columns
                    foreach (IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 extMetadataColumn in extMetadataColumnColl)
                    {
                        // Call the MapOutPutColumn method of the destination to map
                        // each available output column to an external metadata column 
                        wrp2.MapOutputColumn(
                            output.ID, outputColumn.ID, extMetadataColumn.ID, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            md2.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(conn);
            md2.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = conn.ID;
            conn.AcquireConnection(null);




            #region Save Package to FileSystem
            string packageXml = @"C:\Users\test.dtsx";
            XmlDocument myPkgDocument = new XmlDocument();
            p.SaveToXML(ref myPkgDocument, null, null);
            a.SaveToXml(packageXml, p, null);
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use BIML for gods sake :) http://www.bimlscript.com/  and  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/ and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/100550/ - By using their own application you can bypass BIDShelper.

Comment: Take a look at this link too.. Very practical guide and almost what your trying to do. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/130470/?utm_source=SSC&utm_medium=pubemail

Comment: Oh awesome. I'll certainly put this in my queue of things to try out. I'm just about fed up with my C# script, and BIML's looking very appealing at the moment. Ideally, I would just have a script that loads a package to refresh meta-data... and that's it. Unfortunately, it seems /easier/ to script the creation of an entire package through BIML than to use C# for that one function. Thank you for the article! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you are not mapping the input columns to the OLEDB Destination, and after opening the package, if you click on the OLEDB Destination and go to the Mapping section, it will automatically map the columns based on their names. The Foreach loop that is used by others are to loop over columns and map them to the related Destination columns.

There are many articles talking about creating SSIS package dynamically, you can refer to them for more information:

- [Dynamic Data Flow in SSIS using .NET/C#](https://bibestpractice.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/dynamic-data-flow-in-ssis-using-netc/)
- [Programmatically map the columns of a flat file destination?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dda9793e-33fe-4834-af53-b9a78cc6cde8/programmatically-map-the-columns-of-a-flat-file-destination?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Building Packages Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/building-packages-programmatically)
- [Samples for creating SSIS packages programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/12/30/samples-for-creating-ssis-packages-programmatically/)
- [Generating SSIS Packages Programmatically (Part I)](http://blogs.solidq.com/en/businessanalytics/generating-ssis-packages-programmatically-part/)

Comment: Addition to you answer i would suggest using BIML if he wants to create SSIS-packages dynamically. http://www.bimlscript.com/

Comment: @PlaidDK i agree with that

Comment: I don't want to mark this as an answer just yet because I have visited all but one of these pages already before posting a question -- I've tried running a foreach loop where it goes through the IDTSInputColumn100 columns and assigns an ExternalMetadataColumnId, but it hasn't successfully mapped the input columns and ends up returning the error that "input columns cannot be zero." I'll take some time today to review that final page and use its example as a way of running through the input columns to validate external meta data. If not, I'll have to try @PlaidDK 's suggestion of using BIML(?).

Comment: @BenjaminJedd if you are familiar with BIML it is easier to achieve this

Comment: My colleague and I just tried using BIML (which was really terrible to have to install and find patches for), and it seems to be a one-time run unless I learn how to script c# to dynamically do what I was originally trying to do but with BIML. 

I need a /single/ package that runs continuously that pulls in data for each table one at a time, and then loads it into the database dynamically by table_name. The C# script is supposed to load a separate package and update metadata since VS cannot do that on its own. While easy to use and intriguing, BIML does not seem to be the answer for this